# How do I use non-standard table / column names for the models while porting an existing php application to CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have an existing PHP/MySQL application that I want to convert over to CakePHP.
Unfortuaintly I can not change the column names and they do not follow the CakePHP standard.

For example: 
One of the table names is called "user" and its not plural. The primary key is called "user_id" instead of "id". The creation date is called 'generated' instead of "created", ect...

I was hoping there would be a way to define aliases for table names and fields in the CakePHP model but I can't seem to find it. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anyway to define a aliases? I would rather user ID instead of user_id in my CakePHP app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the name of the table associated with a model, as well as the primary key:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $table = 'User';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

As far as the "`generated`" thing, I haven't found a way to override the "`created/modified`" defaults in CakePHP (other than going through the library source and hacking it directly).  Are you able to add columns?

Comment: Yes, I can add columns I would prefer not to thou. I will try you solution tonight. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

About "generated" you can insert/update values with callbacks like beforeSave.

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $table = 'user';
    var $primaryKey = 'user_id'

    function beforeSave() {
        this->data['generated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [AliasBehavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/aliasbehavior) but it has certain limitations (see comments on that article).

Other than that, some basic customisation is in order:

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/436/useTable
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/437/primaryKey
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/438/displayField

As far as I know, there is currently no way to tell cake your *created* field is called *generated*, you'll probably just have to handle that manually, possibly in [Model::beforeSave()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/683/beforeSave).

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP lets you specify anything that is different from the standard conventions it promotes.  Being the egomaniac shill that I am, I can recommend a book about refactoring applications using CakePHP that I wrote.

http://www.easyphpwebsites.com/books/v/Refactoring-Legacy-Applications-Using-CakePHP

Cheap $13 PDF.